# Adding a svelte component to DOM at runtime?

Tags: dynamic, svelte, appendchild, svelte-component

Adding a svelte component (Button) statically in the body section works. Adding the Button via appendChild does not?

Details:

Imagine a database table. For each row I add a line into my HTML body.

How could I add a svelte component (Button.svelte) to each row, too?

The problem: Standard HTML gets appended, but my svelte Button does not. (Probably because svelte needs to render at compile time.)

For example in +page.svelte:

```
const e = document.getElementById('my_div_container');
if(e)
{
    const p = document.createElement("p");
    const txt = document.createTextNode("test node");
    p.appendChild(txt);
    e.appendChild(p); // <-- ok, gets displayed
    const b = document.createElement("Button");
    e.appendChild(b); // <-- NOT displayed
}
```

Example lib/Button.svelte:

```
<script>
    function on_click()
    {
        console.log('clicked');
    }
</script>
<button on:click={() => on_click()}>Click</button>
```

FYI: Statically adding a button to the HTML body works of course:

```
<p>Some text</p>
<Button />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either build components [as custom elements](https://svelte.dev/docs/custom-elements-api), then they can be created with `createElement` or just use the [client component API](https://svelte.dev/docs/client-side-component-api). For that, you need to import the component and construct it, setting the `target` to the element you want to add it to:

```js
new Button({ target: e })
```

Comment: The `as custom elements` link is broken (404), should probably be changed to `https://svelte.dev/docs/client-side-component-api#creating-a-component` ?

Comment: @user2602152: That would be for the second link. I updated both.